# Java возврат строки в лямбда функции

Tags: java

Что нужно сделать чтобы лямбда функция возвращала строку?

Comment: Нужно определить такую функцию)) У вас есть конкретный пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, собственно, ничего такого делать не нужно. Достаточно написать так:

```
number -> number + "x"
```

для преобразования числа в строку и возврата этой самой строки. В виде сохранённой функции это будет выглядеть так:

```
Function<Integer, String> func = number -> number + "x";
```

Или более полный вариант:

```
Function<Integer, String> func = (number) -> { return number + "x"; };
```

В обоих случаях

```
System.out.println(func.apply(10));
```

выводит на экран `10x`.

---

Лямбда-выражение, которое ничего не принимает и возвращает `String`:

```
Supplier<String> func = () -> "x";
System.out.println(func.get());
```

Список функциональных интерфейсов можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: А что не так тогда с этим кодом `Function<Integer, String> func = () -> {return "hello";};`

Comment: @Duoxx потому что `Function` принимает один параметр (в данном случае `Integer`) и возвращает значение (в данном случае `String`). Вы же пытаетесь в `Function` присвоить лямбда-выражение, которое ничего не принимает и возвращает `String`. Для этого нужен `Supplier`: `Supplier<String> func = () -> "hello";`.